# static block not works with @Value in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to seek help on below issue. I am reading some properties from properties file and assign changed/final values to another variables. I am facing difficulties in changing the static{ } block to normal block or in constructor.

I want all these variables to gets assign value from .properties file at the time of web application load / deployment. Any help ?

```
private static String username;
private static String password;
private static String dbURL;
private static String dbPort;
private static String filePath;
private static File localFile;
private static File remoteFile;


@Value("${local.file.name}")
private String localFileName;

@Value("${remote.file.name"})
private String remoteFileName;

    static {
        File finalFilePath = new File(filePath);
        if (!finalFilePath.exists() && !finalFilePath.isDirectory()) {
            finalFilePath.mkdirs();
        }
        localFile = new File(StringBuffer(finalFilePath).append("/").append("localFileName").toString());
        remoteFile = new File(StringBuffer(finalFilePath).append("/").append("remoteFileName").toString());
    }
```

Comment: in what class are these properties (spring-managed bean?, Component, Service, Repository, Configuration)? does that work? (test by debugging some statement in a PostConstruct annotated method)

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago. In this case using `+` would be more efficient and easier to read.

Answer (score 11):

That will never work.
`static` block execution occurs before spring life cycle. Spring will inject those property values (`@Value`) after an instance is created, so, as jny said, you need to use @PostConstructor for example (or any other option spring provides for initialization) instead of static block initialization.

Edit: (add an example)

```
@Value("${local.file.name}")
private String localFileName;

@Value("${remote.file.name"})
private String remoteFileName;


@PostConstruct 
public void setup() {
        File finalFilePath = new File(filePath); // assume filePath is already injected
        if (!finalFilePath.exists() && !finalFilePath.isDirectory()) {
            finalFilePath.mkdirs();
        }
        localFile = new File(StringBuffer(finalFilePath).append("/").append("localFileName").toString());
        remoteFile = new File(StringBuffer(finalFilePath).append("/").append("remoteFileName").toString());
}
```

Thus, I've got `localFile` and `remoteFile` variables ready to use in this bean, after initialization.

More examples here: http://www.journaldev.com/2637/spring-bean-life-cycle-methods-initializingbean-disposablebean-postconstruct-predestroy-aware-interfaces

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Could you please provide sample project for same?  Thanks, Sayali

Answer (score 2):

You can implement method annotated with `@PostConstruct` (or implement `InitializingBean` and implement `afterPropertiesSet`) and set the values there. Spring will call this method after bean initialization at the time of application load.

Answer (score -2):

Check the properties file is in the classpath and also that your class is annotated as a Spring component